# How are template parameters assumed when following specified numbered parameters?

Tags: parameters, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates

As far as I understand, the following function:

```
{{mytemplate|foo|bar|snakes|boat|programming}}
```

has the following parameters automatically filled for it:

```
{{mytemplate|1=foo|2=bar|3=snakes|4=boat|5=programming}}
```

How does the following function autofill when some numbers are defined for it:

```
{{mytemplate|2=foo|bar|snakes|param=boat|3=programming}}
```

with `param=` being equivalent to `1=`?

---

Backstory:

I'm writing a string function that will allow a user to extract parameter arguments from a mediawiki function. I have a mediawiki server installed; if this is possible to do via the API, that would work too in solving my issue. Basically I need a stringlist containing all parameters and their corresponding arguments.

Answer (score 2):

No, `param=boat` means that you have parameter `param` with value `boat`, and `2=foo` means that parameter `2` has value `foo`. So, any other values which are free (with undefined parameters) are for the missing number parameters, which means that in your example:

```
{{mytemplate
|2=foo
|bar                //1=bar
|snakes             //4=snakes (because 2 and 3 are already taken)
|param=boat
|3=programming
}}
```

Or in your template you need to use: `{{{param}}}`, `{{{1}}}`, `{{{2}}}`, `{{{3}}}` and `{{{4}}}`.

Comment: So... parameters are not automatically indexed? Sorry; I find your answer confusing. :)

Comment: Of course, `param` will not be indexed. This is not array, you can put `param` (or some other value which is assigned to some parameter) on any place in the template. Only values without parameters will be indexed automatically.

Comment: After some experimentation, it appears that the values without parameters will left to right, be indexed as 1, 2, 3, 4... without skipping integers, regardless of whether their named parameter has already been specified. The right most parameters will override the left.

Answer (score 2):

> If this is possible to do via the API, that would work too in solving my issue.

Yes, you can use the [`parse` API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse) with parameters `text` and `prop=parsetree`.